# SKSpriteNode Targeting

Tags: objective-c, oop, sprite-kit, skspritenode, sknode

So RIGHT NOW my code presents 7 playing cards. If the playing card is pressed it moves removes the card from the `playerCard` array and adds it to the `playedCards` array. The problem is, is move the card I target it with a SKNode in the `touchesBegan` method;

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];
    if ([node isKindOfClass:[CardSpriteNode class]]) {
```

Okay, no problem, the card moves up. The problem is, All the other cards left in the `playerCards` now need to move i.e ( tighten up ) as they were originally. Here's my formula for distances between them;

```
int cardsLaid = i * (cardDisplay.size.width / 3);
```

So I can now get the cards that are originally displayed and the ones that are touched, to form a nice gap between them.

**What I need to do is to move the cards back to a nice gap, after one of the cards between them has been moved**

```
        for (int i = 0; i < [playerCards count]; i++) {
            int cardsLaid = i * (cardDisplay.size.width / 3);
            CGPoint forPoint = CGPointMake((0.5 - (self.frame.size.width / 4)) + cardsLaid, 0.0);

            playerCards[i] //Here I need to target each skspritenode.name for each playerCards

            [??? runAction:[SKAction moveTo:forPoint duration:0.6]];
        }
```

So I need to target each SKSpritenode.name by the names saved in the `playerCards` MutableArray. Then once I've targetted a spritenode I need to move it where the `???` is.

Here's my entire `touchesBegan` method if it helps.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];
    if ([node isKindOfClass:[CardSpriteNode class]]) {
        int add = (int)[playerCards count] * (cardDisplay.size.width / 3);
        CGPoint origPos = CGPointMake(-self.frame.size.width/2.8 + add, -218);

        if ([cardsPlayed containsObject:node.name]) {
            //Card is already played, return to original position and remove from array.
            CGPoint point = origPos;

            [node runAction:[SKAction moveTo:point duration:0.6]];

            node.zPosition = zPosCount;
            zPosCount += 1;

            [cardsPlayed removeObject:node.name];
            [playerCards addObject:node.name];

            NSLog(@"this ran");
        } else {
            //Card is not already played, position to add card and add to array.
            amountOfCardsLaid = (int)[cardsPlayed count] * (cardDisplay.size.width / 3);
            CGPoint point = CGPointMake((0.5 - (self.frame.size.width / 4
            )) + amountOfCardsLaid, 0.0);
            [node runAction:[SKAction moveTo:point duration:0.6]];

            node.zPosition = zPosCount;
            zPosCount += 1;

            [playerCards removeObject:node.name];
            [cardsPlayed addObject:node.name];

            for (int i = 0; i < [playerCards count]; i++) {
                int cardsLaid = i * (cardDisplay.size.width / 3);
                CGPoint forPoint = CGPointMake((0.5 - (self.frame.size.width / 4)) + cardsLaid, 0.0);

                playerCards[i]

                [??? runAction:[SKAction moveTo:forPoint duration:0.6]];
            }
        }

        //Hide.Unhide buttons
        if ([cardsPlayed count] == 0) {
            if (addButton.hidden == FALSE) addButton.hidden = true;
            if (cancelButton.hidden == FALSE) cancelButton.hidden = true;
        } else {
            if (addButton.hidden == TRUE) addButton.hidden = false;
            if (cancelButton.hidden == TRUE) cancelButton.hidden = false;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

The gap I need to close is on the bottom `playerCards`

Answer (score 0):

```
SKNode *tempNode = [self childNodeWithName:playerCards[i]];
```

After a few days. fml